# Tampermonkey script to replace parts of an link

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

For example i have a link

> https://somefilehostsite.com/file/asodhaisdbaisyd7
> and i want a script to redirect it to
> https://somefilehostsite.com/FilePage2/asodhaisdbaisyd7

This is the script i tried but didn't work.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         DLUpload Skip
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Skip Pages
// @author       Angelo Heide
// @match        https://onlinenepal.net/file/*
// @exclude      https://onlinenepal.net/FilePage2/*
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

location.replace = ("onlinenepal.net/FilePage2/*");
```

Comment: Of course not. I imagine that's not a valid url to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

Just a if statement
If current url is equal to `https://somefilehostsite.com/file/*`
redirect to `https://somefilehostsite.com/FilePage2/asodhaisdbaisyd7`

```
var reg = new RegExp('https://somefilehostsite.com/file/(.*)')
if (reg.test(document.URL))
{
   window.location.replace = 'https://somefilehostsite.com/FilePage2/asodhaisdbaisyd7';
}
```

Link to regex https://regexr.com/5gqtt

Comment: what if i want it to work for not just that link but every link under https://somefilehostsite.com/file/*

Comment: @AngeloHeide i've changed my answer it will work now